# Where to place Entity Framework 6.0 pre-generated view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dll

I'm developing Window Forms project with Entity Framework 6.0. I apply Database-first approach and create edmx file by using Visual Studio Wizards. Like all others, I also produce pre-generated view to improve performance. I used [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d). It works and produce my_EF.views.cs file.

But my first query still take **long time**.

I doubt that my project file structure might be the problem. In my solution explorer, I have two projects "**MyApp.GUI**" (Windows Form Project) and "**MyApp.DataAccess**" (Class Library Project). I add reference **dll** of "MyApp.DataAccess" to "MyApp.GUI".

My Entity Framework **edmx** file is located in "**MyApp.DataAccess**" project. I don't know where to put my pre-generated view file whether in "**MyApp.DataAccess**" class library or "**MyApp.GUI**" windows form project. Currently the pre-generated view file is in "**MyApp.DataAccess**" class library.

Does my problem associated with my project file structure ? Or, may be the pre-generated view file does not work (produced by Entity Framework Power Tools) ? This is my pre-generated view file. Please suggest me possible solutions.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.MappingViews;

[assembly: DbMappingViewCacheTypeAttribute(
    typeof(TheWayPointOfSale.DataAccess.TheWayPOSEntities),
    typeof(Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews.ViewsForBaseEntitySetsa6f884d523752b7a79e1bab1a97ba058ffdac6b45a04cc850e30f503a4e1fc49))]

namespace Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews
{
    using System;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;

/// <summary>
/// Implements a mapping view cache.
/// </summary>
[GeneratedCode("Entity Framework Power Tools", "0.9.0.0")]
internal sealed class ViewsForBaseEntitySetsa6f884d523752b7a79e1bab1a97ba058ffdac6b45a04cc850e30f503a4e1fc49 : DbMappingViewCache
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a hash value computed over the mapping closure.
    /// </summary>
    public override string MappingHashValue
    {
        get { return "a6f884d523752b7a79e1bab1a97ba058ffdac6b45a04cc850e30f503a4e1fc49"; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a view corresponding to the specified extent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="extent">The extent.</param>
    /// <returns>The mapping view, or null if the extent is not associated with a mapping view.</returns>
    public override DbMappingView GetView(EntitySetBase extent)
    {
        if (extent == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("extent");
        }

        var extentName = extent.EntityContainer.Name + "." + extent.Name;

        if (extentName == "TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Products")
        {
            return GetView0();
        }

        if (extentName == "TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Um")
        {
            return GetView1();
        }

        if (extentName == "TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Products_Um")
        {
            return GetView2();
        }

        if (extentName == "TheWayPOSEntities.Products")
        {
            return GetView3();
        }

        if (extentName == "TheWayPOSEntities.Ums")
        {
            return GetView4();
        }

        if (extentName == "TheWayPOSEntities.Products_Um")
        {
            return GetView5();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the view for TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Products.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The mapping view.</returns>
    private static DbMappingView GetView0()
    {
        return new DbMappingView(@"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Products
    [TheWayPOSModel.Store.Products](T1.[Products.product_code], T1.[Products.product_name], T1.[Products.buying_price], T1.[Products.discount_percentage], T1.[Products.retail_price], T1.[Products.wholesale_price], T1.Products_supplier, T1.[Products.created_at], T1.[Products.updated_at])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.product_code AS [Products.product_code], 
        T.product_name AS [Products.product_name], 
        T.buying_price AS [Products.buying_price], 
        T.discount_percentage AS [Products.discount_percentage], 
        T.retail_price AS [Products.retail_price], 
        T.wholesale_price AS [Products.wholesale_price], 
        T.supplier AS Products_supplier, 
        T.created_at AS [Products.created_at], 
        T.updated_at AS [Products.updated_at], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM TheWayPOSEntities.Products AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the view for TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Um.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The mapping view.</returns>
    private static DbMappingView GetView1()
    {
        return new DbMappingView(@"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Um
    [TheWayPOSModel.Store.Um](T1.[Um.um_code], T1.[Um.um_shortname], T1.[Um.um_fullname], T1.Um_disposable, T1.[Um.disposed_um_code], T1.[Um.disposed_um_qty], T1.[Um.depend_on_product], T1.[Um.created_at], T1.[Um.updated_at])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.um_code AS [Um.um_code], 
        T.um_shortname AS [Um.um_shortname], 
        T.um_fullname AS [Um.um_fullname], 
        T.disposable AS Um_disposable, 
        T.disposed_um_code AS [Um.disposed_um_code], 
        T.disposed_um_qty AS [Um.disposed_um_qty], 
        T.depend_on_product AS [Um.depend_on_product], 
        T.created_at AS [Um.created_at], 
        T.updated_at AS [Um.updated_at], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM TheWayPOSEntities.Ums AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the view for TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Products_Um.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The mapping view.</returns>
    private static DbMappingView GetView2()
    {
        return new DbMappingView(@"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Products_Um
    [TheWayPOSModel.Store.Products_Um](T1.[Products_Um.id], T1.[Products_Um.product_code], T1.[Products_Um.um_code], T1.[Products_Um.disposed_um_code], T1.[Products_Um.disposed_um_qty])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.id AS [Products_Um.id], 
        T.product_code AS [Products_Um.product_code], 
        T.um_code AS [Products_Um.um_code], 
        T.disposed_um_code AS [Products_Um.disposed_um_code], 
        T.disposed_um_qty AS [Products_Um.disposed_um_qty], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM TheWayPOSEntities.Products_Um AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the view for TheWayPOSEntities.Products.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The mapping view.</returns>
    private static DbMappingView GetView3()
    {
        return new DbMappingView(@"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Products
    [TheWayPOSModel.Product](T1.[Product.product_code], T1.[Product.product_name], T1.[Product.buying_price], T1.[Product.discount_percentage], T1.[Product.retail_price], T1.[Product.wholesale_price], T1.Product_supplier, T1.[Product.created_at], T1.[Product.updated_at])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.product_code AS [Product.product_code], 
        T.product_name AS [Product.product_name], 
        T.buying_price AS [Product.buying_price], 
        T.discount_percentage AS [Product.discount_percentage], 
        T.retail_price AS [Product.retail_price], 
        T.wholesale_price AS [Product.wholesale_price], 
        T.supplier AS Product_supplier, 
        T.created_at AS [Product.created_at], 
        T.updated_at AS [Product.updated_at], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Products AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the view for TheWayPOSEntities.Ums.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The mapping view.</returns>
    private static DbMappingView GetView4()
    {
        return new DbMappingView(@"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Ums
    [TheWayPOSModel.Um](T1.[Um.um_code], T1.[Um.um_shortname], T1.[Um.um_fullname], T1.Um_disposable, T1.[Um.disposed_um_code], T1.[Um.disposed_um_qty], T1.[Um.depend_on_product], T1.[Um.created_at], T1.[Um.updated_at])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.um_code AS [Um.um_code], 
        T.um_shortname AS [Um.um_shortname], 
        T.um_fullname AS [Um.um_fullname], 
        T.disposable AS Um_disposable, 
        T.disposed_um_code AS [Um.disposed_um_code], 
        T.disposed_um_qty AS [Um.disposed_um_qty], 
        T.depend_on_product AS [Um.depend_on_product], 
        T.created_at AS [Um.created_at], 
        T.updated_at AS [Um.updated_at], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Um AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the view for TheWayPOSEntities.Products_Um.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The mapping view.</returns>
    private static DbMappingView GetView5()
    {
        return new DbMappingView(@"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Products_Um
    [TheWayPOSModel.Products_Um](T1.[Products_Um.id], T1.[Products_Um.product_code], T1.[Products_Um.um_code], T1.[Products_Um.disposed_um_code], T1.[Products_Um.disposed_um_qty])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.id AS [Products_Um.id], 
        T.product_code AS [Products_Um.product_code], 
        T.um_code AS [Products_Um.um_code], 
        T.disposed_um_code AS [Products_Um.disposed_um_code], 
        T.disposed_um_qty AS [Products_Um.disposed_um_qty], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM TheWayPOSModelStoreContainer.Products_Um AS T
) AS T1");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the generated view class, and try figure out where you have to place the file for your breakpoint to be hit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this information is not worth to be an answer. But for other newbies like me, I would like to share my experience.

According to Maarten's comment, I have put breakpoints in each of the pre-generated view files. The pre-generated view in **DataAccess** class library is hit by the breakpoint. So, it can be generally assume to place the pre-generated view file in **DataAccess** class library where edmx file is located (in my kinds of situations).